# Change link colors in output window of MPLAB X IDE v5.45

Tags: microchip, mplab, mplab-5.45

I'm using MPLAB X IDE v5.45 under Ubuntu and due to my color setup the links in the output window are almost unreadable:

[image]

I went through Tools > Options > Font & Colors but I didn't find anything useful.
Please, would you help me to understand how to change the color of those links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on MPLAB X v5.35 for Windows, but this should apply to your installation as well.

The colors of the output window can be changed in the "Options > Miscellaneous > Output" Tab.
[image: MPLAB X Options Window]

Comment: Yes! I confirm it works also on my setup.